# .htaccess add tablet redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using the .htaccess file, I wish to redirect tablet traffic to a tablet optimised site.

Regular URL: waxxxed.com.au
Tablet Optimised URL: waxxxed.com.au/tablet/

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipad [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ipad\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://waxxxed.com.au/tablet/ [L,R=301]
```

x3 questions...

1. This code doesn't work. Appears to create a loop. Not sure, but that may be related to my existing .htaccess code provided below.
2. I want to redirect ALL tablets (not mobiles) not just iPads. How do I capture other tablet brands?
3. Can you recommend any further optimisation of my .htaccess coding.

Full current .htaccess file (it works!)...

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable cache expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”
</IfModule>

# force redirect of html to no-extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)\.html$ http://waxxxed.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.waxxxed.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://waxxxed.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect from / to non-/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]

# parse file as file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)$ $1.html [L] 

# refer not found content to 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

Comment: As a general warning: You will *never* capture *all* tablets just by looking at the User-Agent string. It changes over time, is constantly spoofed by browsers wanting you to think they're something more popular, and doesn't really ask the right question - i.e. what is it about tablets that you actually want to redirect for? Small screens? Touchscreens? Portability? Does an iPad mini have the same requirements as a Surface Pro? What about a Galaxy Note? What future devices might come along?

Comment: Very good points. Ultimately I wish to optimise the experience based on screen size. I have a mobile site which is redirecting as it should via alternative means, but I'll change the redirection to the .htaccess once I've figured out the tablet requirements. iPad mini is something I hadn't considered and thank you for mentioning this. I guess I'll start with the basics, get them working, and then expand to others.

Thank you for taking the time to write this response.

Comment: If you're interested in screen size, I would advise against moving the logic to the Apache configuration - an HTTP request contains no reliable information about screen size. Instead, use JS to measure the actual screen size when the user lands on the first page of the site, or CSS media queries to render the same HTML in different ways.

Comment: Here's a nice example of why categorising every browser into "phone, tablet, or PC" and assuming that tells you about screen size is a bad idea: https://twitter.com/BobParody/status/345661809342156800 And that's just one company's range!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it creates a loop is because you're checking that the **hostname** doesn't start with `ipad`, and since you're redirecting to `waxxxed.com.au`, it's never going to start with `ipad`. Instead check for the request URI starting with `/tablet/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipad [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tablet/. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://waxxxed.com.au/tablet/ [L,R=301]
```

As for #2, you need to lookup user-agents for other tablets. In general, you want to find "android" but *not* "mobile":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !mobile [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tablet/. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://waxxxed.com.au/tablet/ [L,R=301]
```

The rest of your htaccess file looks fine as long as it's doing what you expect, anything would be really nit-picky.

Comment: Been trialling this code and appears to work fine if a click is made on the desktop homepage (ie correctly redirects iPad to iPad version of site). Problem is... if they select another desktop URL from a Google search (ie the about us page). iPad users don't redirect to the optimised site but instead go to the regular page. Here's the code as it stands... 

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPad" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tablet/. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://waxxxed.com.au/tablet/$1 [L,R=301]